# Finding the Largest File in a Folder With Anonymous Type and the IComparable Interface

Tags: c#

While am executing,code getting an error i don't know where i have to make change to implement interface.
below is my full code that i tried with console application

```
  Error 1   'ConsoleApplication16.Temp' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable<ConsoleApplication16.Temp>.CompareTo(ConsoleApplication16.Temp)'    D:\nnn\ConsoleApplication16\ConsoleApplication16\Program.cs 32  18  ConsoleApplication16
```

Below is my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()

    {
    string []files=Directory.GetFiles("C:\\WINDOWS","*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    Console.WriteLine(files.Count());
   //Get Maximum
   var max = (from fileName in files
                  let info = new FileInfo(fileName)
                  orderby info.Length descending
                  select new { FileName = info.Name, Size = info.Length })
                  .Take(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Using Take : {0}",max.ElementAt(0));
        //With anonymous Type we have to indicate what to get the max of
        var max2 = (from fileName in files
                    let info = new FileInfo(fileName)
                    select
                    new Temp{ FileName = info.Name, Size = info.Length })
                    .Max(s => s.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Using Max:{0}", max2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Temp : IComparable<Temp> //error is here
{
    public string FileName { set; get; }
    public long Size { set; get; }

    public int compareTo(Temp o)
    {
        return Size.CompareTo(o.Size);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("FileName:{0},Size:{1}", FileName, Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to capitalize the first letter of the first word after a period.  So in the question posted, "below..." should be "Below...".  Also i should be I.  Likewise, compareTo() should be CompareTo().  The point is that "case matters".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is case sensitive, it is `CompareTo` instead of `compareTo`

```
public int CompareTo(Temp o)
{
    return Size.CompareTo(o.Size);
}
```

However, i don't know how this compiler error is related to the rest of the code since `CompareTo` is never used in your LINQ query.